# Python solving equation and graphing the results

Tags: python, graphing

I trying to solve Kepler's Equation using python with known 'x' and 'e' values, trying to find 'y'. The equation is `x=y-(e*sin(y))`. I need to step through an array of x, with a range of min=0 and max=pi, with 1000 steps, and a value of e=0.1, solve for y and plot the graph. I am getting an error why 'y' is undefined, but 'y' is what I am trying to find, so I am stuck.

```py
x = np.linspace(0, math.pi, 1000)  
e = 0.1

y = Symbol('y')

Solve(x = y-(e*math.sin(y)))

FIG1, MA = plt.plots(figsize=(4, 3))


MA.plot(x, y)

MA.set_xlabel('Mean Anomely')

MA.set_ylabel('Mean Eccentricity')

MA.set_title('Keplers equation')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please always add the import statements to make your example code self-contained and easily reproducible. Most people might know that `np` is numpy, but it is unclear where the function `Solve` in your example comes from.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the inverse function of `x=y-(e*sin(y))` to get `y(x)`. You will not find a symbolic solution, so you need to solve it numerically. A standard trick for this is computing values of `x` for given `y` and do an interpolation. This is possible, because the function is monotonic and continuous.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

e = 0.1

# select many points for interpolation, e.g. 2000
E_values = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 2000)
M_values = E_values - e*np.sin(E_values)

# do the interpolation on your selected points for M
M_interp = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 1000)
E_interp = np.interp(M_interp, M_values, E_values)

# plot the stuff
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
ax.plot(M_interp, E_interp)
ax.set_xlabel('Mean Anomaly')
ax.set_ylabel('Eccentric Anomaly')
```

Note that I used the more frequently used symbols M and E for mean anomaly and eccentric anomaly.